# Alternative to python string item assignment

Tags: python, string

What is the best / correct way to use item assignment for python string ?

i.e `s = "ABCDEFGH"` `s[1] = 'a'` `s[-1]='b'` ?

Normal way will throw : `'str' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Strings are immutable. That means you can't assign to them at all. You could use formatting:

```
>>> s = 'abc{0}efg'.format('d')
>>> s
'abcdefg'
```

Or concatenation:

```
>>> s = 'abc' + 'd' + 'efg'
>>> s
'abcdefg'
```

Or replacement (thanks Odomontois for reminding me):

```
>>> s = 'abc0efg'
>>> s.replace('0', 'd')
'abcdefg'
```

But keep in mind that all of these methods create *copies* of the string, rather than modifying it in-place. If you want in-place modification, you could use a `bytearray` -- though that will only work for plain ascii strings, as alexis points out.

```
>>> b = bytearray('abc0efg')
>>> b[3] = 'd'
>>> b
bytearray(b'abcdefg')
```

Or you could create a list of characters and manipulate that. This is probably the most efficient and correct way to do frequent, large-scale string manipulation:

```
>>> l = list('abc0efg')
>>> l[3] = 'd'
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> ''.join(l)
'abcdefg'
```

And consider the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module for more complex operations.

String formatting and list manipulation are the two methods that are most likely to be correct and efficient IMO -- string formatting when only a few insertions are required, and list manipulation when you need to frequently update your string.

Comment: Also str.replace() and re.RegexObject.sub methods could be useful.

Comment: bytearray looks good to me, is there anyway to convert string to byte array ?

Comment: @iKid, in the above code, `'abc0efg'` is a string, and `bytearray('abc0efg')` converts that string into a bytearray. So yes :)

Comment: Don't use `bytearray`. If your string contains non-English characters (unicode or other encodings), bytearray will break them up and you can end up with nonsense. Also, it's an array of integers, not of characters, which has all sorts of weird effects. Anyway keep in mind that strings are immutable in python for a reason. It makes life easier in all sorts of ways.

Comment: You could mention the bytearray class - it supports several strign methos, and does support item assignment.

Answer (score 8):

Since strings are "immutable", you get the effect of editing by constructing a modified version of the string and assigning it over the old value. If you want to replace or insert to a specific position in the string, the most array-like syntax is to use slices:

```
s = "ABCDEFGH" 
s = s[:3] + 'd' + s[4:]   # Change D to d at position 3
```

It's more likely that you want to replace a particular character or string with another. Do that with `re`, again collecting the result rather than modifying in place:

```
import re
s = "ABCDEFGH"
s = re.sub("DE", "--", s)
```

Comment: As a python n00b, this was exactly what I wanted to change a character at a particular position.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this Object could help:

```
class Charray(list):

    def __init__(self, mapping=[]):
        "A character array."
        if type(mapping) in [int, float, long]:
            mapping = str(mapping)
        list.__init__(self, mapping)

    def __getslice__(self,i,j):
        return Charray(list.__getslice__(self,i,j))

    def __setitem__(self,i,x):
        if type(x) <> str or len(x) > 1:
            raise TypeError
        else:
            list.__setitem__(self,i,x)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "charray['%s']" % self

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(self)
```

For example:

```
>>> carray = Charray("Stack Overflow")
>>> carray
charray['Stack Overflow']
>>> carray[:5]
charray['Stack']
>>> carray[-8:]
charray['Overflow']
>>> str(carray)
'Stack Overflow'
>>> carray[6] = 'z'
>>> carray
charray['Stack zverflow']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "ABCDEFGH" s[1] = 'a' s[-1]='b'
```

you can use like this

```
s=s[0:1]+'a'+s[2:]
```

this is very simple than other complex ways