# How to change all the letter that were in a position that is multiple of 2?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to change the position of a character/letter that is multiple of 2 with the character `*`. However, when I try to run it I get an error message

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

```
def guess(x):
    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x[i] = "*"
            i = i + 1
    return x
    print(guess("today is a beautiful day"))
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to python string item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453820/alternative-to-python-string-item-assignment)

Comment: In addition to Samwise's answer below, it's worth highlighting the differences between their approach and your own. Constructing a for loop with `enumerate(x)` is a great way to iterate through the string, returning the index and character value, instead of setting up a clunky while loop and having to create a counter working through it.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable, so you'll need to build a new string to return.  I'd use `enumerate` and `join`:

```
>>> def guess(x):
...     return ''.join(c if i % 2 else '*' for i, c in enumerate(x))
...
>>> guess("today is a beautiful day")
'*o*a* *s*a*b*a*t*f*l*d*y'
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error message, a string object does not support item assignment like lists and dictionaries. I suggest using the `replace()` function for your code or changing `x` into a list and then back into a string.

Comment: `replace` replaces characters by value, not by position.

Comment: Yeah I see what you were trying to do. Samwise's code will work just fine. As i said, you can also change ```x``` into a list since lists support item assignments. Then just return x using ```return ''.join(x)```. I also dont know why you are using a while loop for this since a for loop would be easier.